Redirecting page after intro screen
Can someone help me with this
I have 3 intro pages, when user reaches the last intro page then i want it to be redirected auto to home page with a delay like 5 sec, or i would like to replace the icons with a button to redirect to homepage.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class OnBoardMain extends StatelessWidget {
  OnBoardMain({super.key});
  final _controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _controller,
              children: const [
                OnBoardScreen(),
                OnBoardScreen2(),
                OnBoardScreen3(),
              ],

              ///

              ///
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _controller,
              count: 3,
              effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                activeDotColor: Colors.black,
                dotColor: Colors.white,
                dotHeight: 8,
                dotWidth: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}




Convert your OnBoardMain from Stateless to Stateful.

//for replace smooth page indicator with a button and on click on that button navigate to another screen.
class OnBoardMain extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardMain({super.key});

  @override
  State<OnBoardMain> createState() => _OnBoardMainState();
}

class _OnBoardMainState extends State<OnBoardMain> {
  final _controller = PageController();

  bool isLastPage = false;

  void _navigate() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return const AnotherScreen();
    }));
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.page == 2.0) {
        setState(() {
          isLastPage = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _controller.animateTo(1.0,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.linear);
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _controller,
              children: const [
                OnBoardScreen(),
                OnBoardScreen2(),
                OnBoardScreen3(),
              ],

              ///

              ///
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: isLastPage
                ? CupertinoButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
                        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt_outlined)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _navigate();
                    })
                : SmoothPageIndicator(
                    controller: _controller,
                    count: 3,
                    effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                      activeDotColor: Colors.blue,
                      dotColor: Colors.black,
                      dotHeight: 8,
                      dotWidth: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


//for auto navigate after 5 seconds to another screen from last page of intro

//update initState()

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.page == 2.0) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) {
          _navigate();
        });
      }
    });
  }


remove the button code and just show smooth page indicator

  Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _controller,
              count: 3,
              effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                activeDotColor: Colors.blue,
                dotColor: Colors.black,
                dotHeight: 8,
                dotWidth: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ),

